# How do I prevent a line of JavaScript from running in IE (but let it run in other browsers)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I am looking for something similar to CSS's `<!--[if IE]>` decaration for JavaScript. I don't have time to find out why a line of code is not working in IE, and commenting it out doesn't break the page, so I am thinking "stuff IE" and looking for a way to comment the line out *only* for IE.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

navigator.appName will contain the browsers name, in your case you are looking for 'Microsoft Internet Explorer' so that would be your condition in this case:

```
if (navigator.appName != 'Microsoft Internet Explorer')
```

I would search for better browser detection than this since this is as simple and small as it gets.

Answer (score 2):

Conditional comments will work fine for this, too.

```
<!--[if IE]>
<script>alert("Hi, this is IE!");</script>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the (deprecated but entirely functional) [`$.browser.msie`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/) jQuery functionality.

(You could also copy the line of code over and we could see if we can see the IE issue.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3986564/why-doesnt-ie-let-me-create-img-elements-using-jquery